# Maven - Package does not exist

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build my project and I keep getting an error, saying the package doesn't exist why the IDE says it's fine (no compile error). Obviously, something is not consistent between my pom.xml and the way the IDE compiles.

Here how my project structure looks like:
[image]

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"><modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.oo</groupId>
    <artifactId>employeeservice</artifactId> <!-- Docker complains if the name contains upper case -->
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>EmployeeService</name>
    <description>This service takes care of all the employee related operations</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I remove Employee (entity) and EmployeeRepository and just have the controller with a dummy "Hello World", it works fine! I tried to put them under the same package, same issue!

**Employee class**

```
package com.oo.employeeservice.dao.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String firtName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirtName() {
        return firtName;
    }

    public void setFirtName(String firtName) {
        this.firtName = firtName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

**Using default Spring boot configuration:**

```
package com.oo.employeeservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.oo.employeeservice.controller;

import com.oo.employeeservice.dao.EmployeeRepository;
import com.oo.employeeservice.dao.entity.Employee;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Employee>> all() {
        return new ResponseEntity<Iterable<Employee>>(repo.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        repo.save(employee);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

Maven log:

```
~/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building EmployeeService 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ employeeservice ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ employeeservice ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ employeeservice ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/dao/EmployeeRepository.java:[3,41] package com.oo.employeeservice.dao.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/dao/EmployeeRepository.java:[9,60] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Employee
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/controller/EmployeeController.java:[4,41] package com.oo.employeeservice.dao.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/controller/EmployeeController.java:[18,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Employee
  location: class com.oo.employeeservice.controller.EmployeeController
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/controller/EmployeeController.java:[23,50] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Employee
  location: class com.oo.employeeservice.controller.EmployeeController
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/controller/EmployeeController.java:[19,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Employee
  location: class com.oo.employeeservice.controller.EmployeeController
[INFO] 6 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.872 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-15T15:59:38+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/308M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project employeeservice: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/dao/EmployeeRepository.java:[3,41] package com.oo.employeeservice.dao.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/dao/EmployeeRepository.java:[9,60] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Employee
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/controller/EmployeeController.java:[4,41] package com.oo.employeeservice.dao.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/controller/EmployeeController.java:[18,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Employee
[ERROR]   location: class com.oo.employeeservice.controller.EmployeeController
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/controller/EmployeeController.java:[23,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Employee
[ERROR]   location: class com.oo.employeeservice.controller.EmployeeController
[ERROR] /home/mahdi/IdeaProjects/EmployeeService/src/main/java/com/oo/employeeservice/controller/EmployeeController.java:[19,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Employee
[ERROR]   location: class com.oo.employeeservice.controller.EmployeeController
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Updated the post by adding Employee object. I did clean package it, but didn't really help.

Comment: It seems ok. Try clean the `target` folder and re-package.

Comment: I believe clean build would do the same. Anyway, I did that and it didn't really make any difference.

Comment: Go to your directory where pom.xml is present, run "mvn clean install" from command line and then try to update project.

Comment: @Yogendra123, didn't really help. Same error. Let me put the complete error in the post

Comment: Check whether com -> oo -> employeeservice -> dao -> entity folders exists in your project directory or not ?

Comment: `Compiling 3 source files`, seems maven did not compile `Employee` to target folder. In my computer, it shows `Compiling 4 source files` and works fine.

Comment: Could it be a file permission issue with the `entity` directory? Is the IDE and bash running under the same user?

Comment: I checked the permissions of the folders and the files, they are identical to other files and folders. I used ls -la to check them. It's weird that it takes only 3 of the files!

Answer (score 1):

I found the silliest problem with Intellij. If you look for Employee class in the package explorer in the image attached, you can see the file is marked as a class. When I opened the file location in the terminal, I realized it doesn't have ".java" extension. Obviously, maven won't recognize the file as a java file!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue once. The problem was I have created the folder structure with name **test.demo.exmple.java** and it got created in the same way in explorer ( this can be seen if you open same files on explorer) means folder name was **test.demo** where the system is looking for test/demo/example.java.

So in your case I think path would be **com.oo.employeeservice** instead of **com/oo/employeeservice**